# YAML enum object representation

Tags: rust, yaml

I have this use case that I will explain in Rust. How do I represent equivalent in YAML

```
enum MainEnum {
    Opt1(T1),
    Opt2(T2)
}

struct T1 {
   x: u32,
}

struct T2 {
   y: bool
}
```

How do I represent this in YAML? I want YaML to either have the x field or y field depending on which Enum value is being selected in YAML.

This program does not run. Any ideas?

```
use serde_yaml;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct T1 {
    x: bool,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct T2 {
    y: u32,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum MainEnum {
    Opt1(T1),
    Opt2(T2),
}

fn main() {
     let config = r#"
---
- Opt1
    x: "true"
"#;

     let me: MainEnum = serde_yaml::from_str(&config).unwrap();
     println!("{:?}", me);
}
```

runtime error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Scan(ScanError { mark: Marker { index: 17, line: 4, col: 5 }, info: "mapping values are not allowed in this context" })', src/main.rs:27:25
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue seems to be the YAML syntax you use. For a map in YAML you need to terminate the parent with a `:` so

```rust
     let config = r#"
---
- Opt1:
  x: true
"#;
```

would be actually correct YAML. But since you are asking serde_yaml for one instance of MainEnum, not for a list (a vec, for example) of MainEnum, it does not expect a YAML sequence but a single entry:

```rust
fn main() {
     let config = r#"
---
Opt1:
  x: true
"#;

     let me: MainEnum = serde_yaml::from_str(&config).unwrap();
     println!("{:?}", me);
}
```

This parses: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=029279e1e6baa77611c2a36e7d5bc3a4